# Can not addEventSource dynamically

Tags: fullcalendar

For a visual of this, please go to http://dc37.dawsoncollege.qc.ca/jonathan/fullcalendar.jpg

I am trying to build a page where I see the weekly schedule of student A.

On the left of the schedule, I have in a html table ( Courses ) all the courses of Student A is taking. I click on a course row and then below that table, still on the right of the schedule I see another html table ( Tutors) that can help Student A with said course.

So then I click on Student B ( Tutor ), I would like Student B's weekly schedule to add on top of Student A ( Tutee ).  I do get the appropriate info and I do have the new data in calevents:

[{"id":"306","title":"Free Time","start":"2011-04-04 08:00:00","end":"2011-04-04 09:00:00","allDay":false,"color":"#ff4500","textColor":"#FFFFFF"},{"id":"307","title":"Free Time","start":"2011-04-04 14:00:00","end":"2011-04-04 22:00:00","allDay":false,"color":"#ff4500","textColor":"#FFFFFF"},{"id":"308","title":"Free Time","start":"2011-04-05 16:00:00","end":"2011-04-05 22:00:00","allDay":false,"color":"#ff4500","textColor":"#FFFFFF"},{"id":"309","title":"Free Time","start":"2011-04-06 16:00:00","end":"2011-04-06 22:00:00","allDay":false,"color":"#ff4500","textColor":"#FFFFFF"},{"id":"310","title":"Free Time","start":"2011-04-07 16:00:00","end":"2011-04-07 22:00:00","allDay":false,"color":"#ff4500","textColor":"#FFFFFF"},{"id":"311","title":"Free Time","start":"2011-04-08 16:00:00","end":"2011-04-08 22:00:00","allDay":false,"color":"#ff4500","textColor":"#FFFFFF"}]

In the end, the schedule never appears on the calendar with the code below.

Subsequently I will want to click on Student C's name and then Student B's schedule removes and then Student C's is overlayed.

```
   $("#tutors tr").live("click", function() {
        var student_number = $(this).find(".student_number").html();

        alert("student tutor click: " + student_number);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get.schedule.php",
            data: {
                action: 'get',
                student_number: student_number,
                color: '#ff4500'
            },
            success:function(calevents){
                alert(calevents);

                $('#matchCalendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', calevents);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are there any javascript errors with the rest of your code? Does the alert show up? Did you load the fullCalendar module? Is calevents formatted correctly?

Comment: The get.schedule.php with the same options feed Student A's schedule.

Comment: I looked there at first.  I forgot to mention.  No errors whatsoever.

Comment: Also, all the alerts show.  I see the student number and I see the contents of calevents, which is posted above.

Comment: And lastly, I'm using FullCalendar 1.5

Comment: Does your JSON have these fields: header, editable, events.  That is what `view source` showed me when I looked at the example they gave...

Comment: ah no...  where would they go in the json data?

Answer (score 0):

This is what they did:

```
{
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
            end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
        }
    ]
}
```

Did you check out the [basic usage](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/) page?

There is also this documentation for the [Event Source](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) object.  There are a few ways to specify how it is formatted, but I don't think yours fits the bill... You might need an events array, events function, or update url.  Not sure about it though...

Comment: oh that stuff.  I have that defined already.  No problem.  The base calendar is there and working.  This the code above is for the onclick on the student B and then his schedule gets overlayed on top of Student A

Comment: I added some stuff... does your calendar display without the ajax call?

Comment: which ajax call.  the call for the Student A schedule or Student B schedule?